# need suggestion for creating bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

Getting P1 alerts when the status of a table doesn't get updated by logger, we need to be able to log the data and update the status based on the following conditions. For now we are using this script to run it when alerted and look into scheduling it later

1. Check If there are any tables with status = 1 that are older than 5mins in the following 2 tables

   **select * from test1 where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);**

   **select * test2  where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);**
2. If we find any records in step# 1 save the output to log from the above query and check if the table specified in TEMP_TABLE_NAME(eg:TEMP_test1) exists, because here temp table automatically gets generated.
3. If the temp table doesn't exist update the status to 0 to clear out the alert, update could be needed for just one of the table listed above

   **Update test1 set status = 0 where ID = ;**
4. If the TEMP_TABLE_NAME(eg:TEMP_test1) does exist, we need to reach out to concerned team to investigate
5. Email the results of the output from step: 1 to xxx@gmail.com for review

I have tried writing below code using google but stucked about stoirng file and how to compare temp table exists or not.

```
email="pqrs@gmail.com"
pid=$$
logFile="/tmp/alertlog"
emailflag=0

host=XX.XX.XX.XX
user=ABC
passwd=XYZ


alert_on_error () {
    echo $1 >> /tmp/$pid.count
    cat /tmp/$pid.count | mail -s "Error running $0 on `hostname`"  $email
    rm -rf /tmp/$pid.*
    exit 1
}

mysql="mysql --connect-timeout=50 --compress --quick --disable-auto-rehash --skip-column-names -u $user -h $host -p$passwd -A"
    ID1='$mysql -e "select * from test1 where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);"'
ID2='$mysql -e select * from test2 where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);"'
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the same `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement as the `SELECT` statement? Then you don't need to save the ID anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar you meant to say instead of storing in log ile ,need to use select query in update like below  Update TEST1 set status = 0 where ID = (select ID from test1 where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ;

Comment: You can still use the `SELECT` to store in log files.

Comment: @barmar can you help me with sample script? actually I am new to this.

Comment: @Barmar updated question with new details

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put everything in a `.sql` file and execute it. E.g. create `myscript.sql`

```
select * from TEST1 where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
select * from TEST2 where status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
UPDATE TEST1 SET status = 0 WHERE status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
UPDATE TEST2 SET status = 0 WHERE status = 1 and CREATED < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

Then execute

```
mysql databasename < myscript.sql >> logfile.txt
```

Comment: yes previously I did same, but i need to setup email too to send alert.because it is logger file.

Comment: That's not in the question. You could use `tee` to write to a logfile and also pipe to `mail`.

Comment: Please add what you've tried. We're not here to write all the code for you.

Comment: I need code to check table is exists or not